# grails spring security core - adding security to the hidden scaffolded actions

Tags: grails

One can use things annotations like:

```
  @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
```

on an actions or on an entire class (seems to work fine), to apply the security control provided by spring security core.  Is there a way to apply security to the hidden scaffolded actions, without applying the security constraint to the whole class?  I want to use one security constraint for some actions, and a different one for the hidden scaffolded actions.

NOTE: if this isn't immediately do-able/answerable, please disregard, as I will generate the code and include it in that way.  I searched and didn't see it, so I'm just wondering if someone knows how to do / if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using annotations you can secure non-annotated urls with the `grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules` config property - see section "5.1 Defining Secured Annotations" in [the docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/)