# grails: "business controller" plus an admin scaffold=true controller

Tags: grails

I have a Registration model and an associated RegistrationController.   Here I bring the user through various steps in the registration process.

I guess I could use an admin tool to administer the database with a secure interface to the host server for site administrative people, but can I also scaffold another registration controller for admin access (probably more intuitive for them to use)?   This one would only be used on existing registrations, like the ability to add notes (a field) and view registrations easily, possibly making other needed fixes/updates to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason the views can't exist in the same controller?  That being said - there's nothing preventing you from creating an AdminRegistrationController and just copying all of the RegistrationController into it.  It's just duplicating ALOT of code unnecessarily - you could instead restrict access to the views that only the admin users should have access to.

Comment: Will this work if I don't want to generate views and actions?  I guess the question is, can I do scaffold = true in the same controller that I define other actions in?  It looks like from a previous question on securing scaffolded actions I ran into this, but it was a couple years ago and I don't remember (was away from Grails).  Question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364750/grails-spring-security-core-adding-security-to-the-hidden-scaffolded-actions?rq=1

Comment: Well you could always create a new SecureRegistrationController and do static scaffold=Registration